# Как проверить наличие только английских букв с символами пунктуации в строке Java Script

Tags: javascript, node.js, регулярные-выражения, строки

Есть два названия видео:

```
let titles = [
    'JavaScript Tutorial for Beginners: Learn JavaScript in 1 Hour',
    'JavaScript Основы для Начинающих - Полный Курс за 6 часов [2020]'
 ]
```

В каждом из них есть пробелы, цифры, различные символы. Мне нужно условие, которое из этого массива вернёт только первую строчу так как в ней содержится только английский язык.
Я пробовал использовать регулярное выражение:

```
titles.forEach(t => {
  if(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(t) === true) {
      console.log(t)
  }
})
```

Такой подход не даёт нужного результата из-за присутствия пробелов и других символов в строках.

**Указывать все символы (!";%?%.), которые могут встретиться в названии видео, я думаю не очень правильно т.к. всех символов не укажешь и могут встретиться какие-то непредсказуемые.
Так же вместо русского языка, может быть любой другой, который тоже нужно исключить
**

Comment: попробуйте от обратного регуляркой, где нет русских букв

Comment: Можно как явно включить все перечисленные ```[!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~]```, так и воспользоваться `[[:punct:]]`, но я не знаю какая у нее поддержка.

Answer (score 0):

как вариант искать русские буквы в строке

```
function testInput(re, str) {
  if (str.search(re) != -1) {
    console.log(true);
  } else {
    console.log(false);
  }

}

const testString  = 'hey JuDe а';
const re = /[А-яЁё]/;

testInput(re, testString);
```

Comment: Не стоит использовать `А-я`, в этот радиус попадут лишние символы, которые вы не ожидаете. UPD: Беру свои слова обратно, похоже проблемы только с `A-z`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let titles = [
    'JavaScript Tutorial for Beginners: Learn JavaScript in 1 Hour',
    'JavaScript Основы для Начинающих - Полный Курс за 6 часов [2020]'
 ]
titles.forEach(t => {
  if(/^[a-zA-Z\d\s!"#$%&'()*+,-.\/:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~]+$/.test(t) === true) {
      console.log(t)
  }
})
```

Comment: проверка ` === true` бессмысленна

Comment: Я взял за основу код из вопроса и поменял в нем регулярное выражение.